# Teradata Stored Procedure - How to get error message text from error handler

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, teradata

is there a way how to beside of SQLCODE and SQLSTATE return the actual error message text?

Of course I can look for the error message in DBC.ERRORMSGS by SQLCODE but clearly I am not able to resolve the error-related object names from there.

Fe. all I can get from DBC.ERRORMSGS is 'Object '%VSTR' does not exist.'

Is there a way how to resolve the object name so I would get something like 'Object DATABASEXOXO.TABLEXOXO does not exist.'?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teradata supports Standard SQL's error handling, i.e there's a "diagnostic area" and one of it's fields is MESSAGE_TEXT which holds the error text. It's usually accessed in condition handler using the GET DIAGNOSTIC statement like this:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 myval = MESSAGE_TEXT;
```

Check the Stored Procedure manual for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer pointed me to the right direction. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MESSAGE_TEXT is limited to 128 characters. With newer versions of Teradata a single column/table name can be 128 characters. So from the diagnostics you cannot always get the full error message out. The only other way I know is through dbc.qrylog.ErrorText. But the qrylog is not always up to date and must be turned on.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table log_table (log_msg varchar(2000), added_ts timestamp(0));

replace procedure sp_error_test
(
IN in_database varchar(50), IN in_table varchar(50), IN in_column varchar(50)
)
begin
  declare l_sql varchar(2000);
  declare l_err varchar(2000);

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
  FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 l_err = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    INSERT INTO log_table VALUES ( 'State: ' || :SQLSTATE || ' Code:' || :SQLCODE ||
      ' Msg: ' || l_err, Current_Timestamp(0));  
  END;

  -- dynamic sql to track execution of --
  set l_sql = 'update ' || in_database || '.' || in_table || 
    ' set ' || in_column || '=' || in_column || ' ';
  execute immediate l_sql;  
end;

call sp_error_test('Dbc','NON_EXISTENT_TABLE','non_existent_column');
select top 100 * from log_table order by added_ts desc;
```

Output:

```
State: 42000 Code:  3807 Msg: Object 'DBC.NON_EXISTENT_TABLE' does not exist.
```